# Calculate color that differs from background and foreground

Tags: algorithm, user-interface, colors

Look at the following picture

[image]

I specified three colors: background, foreground and frame. They look OK to me. A user is able to change only background and foreground colors. How can I automatically calculate frame color and be sure it differs from both background and foreground colors (it would be great if this color won't look too terrible).

**EDIT**

Treat given colors as default color schema. So, there are 3 hardcoded colors that are used by default. But, a user is able to set custom background and/or foreground color. So, even if frame color is known for default background/foreground colors, it should be automatically calculated for all custom background/foreground colors that user is able to specify.

Constants:

- `bkg_color` - default background color
- `frg_color` - default foreground color
- `frame_color` - default frame color

Input:

- `custom_bkg_color` - custom background color
- `custom_frg_color` - custom foreground color

Output:

```
custom_frame_color =
    f(bkg_color, frg_color, frame_color, custom_bkg_color, custom_frg_color)
```

Color is 24 bit RGB. The picture is just for the sake of visualization.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the picture will have that shape necessarily? If yes then you just need to grab the pixel color in the top left corner (first pixel) and of the pixel in the center to get the color of the background (first pixel) and of the foreground (center pixel). Then you can for example calculate the average value between them and that will give you a different color. It is possible that the "average" color is very similar to the other two if they are similar between them. You can do some other operation if that is the case.